# element of odd finite group has unique square root

Tags: abstract-algebra

let G be an odd finite group show that each element of G has a unique square root (if $x \in G$ then there exists $y \in G$ such that $x=y^2$)

Is this problem right?
If there is another condition such as G is commutative, I can solve this problem
But with only this, My logic fails.
My question is that "do this problem without condition: abelian,  make sense?? Is there any counterexamples? (odd finite group but there exists an element which doesn't have square root)"

Comment: What is the problem? Are you asking if there is a group with an odd number of elements such that each element has a unique square root?

Comment: ahow -》show   i edited answer

Answer (score 9):

First we prove that the square root (if it exists) is unique:  If $\#G=2k-1$ and $g_1^2=g_2^2$ then we write $$g_1=g_1^{2k}=(g_1^2)^{k}=(g_2^2)^k=g_2^{2k}=g_2$$

Now we remark that this suffices.  Indeed, if $f:S\to S$ is a function from a finite set to itself, then injectivity is equivalent to surjectivity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! (:    you say that your function f is bijective and therefore all elements of G have the unique square root. And so the problem don't need another condition. Right???  Did i understand you correctly?

Comment: Correct.  No other conditions are needed.

Comment: Ohhhh  thank you thankyou very much... i have considered this problem for two days... im so stupid... haha  thank you!!!!

Comment: Not at all!  I've been doing this for a very long time.