# Is there an efficient formula for computing point halving on elliptic curves in $\operatorname{char}F=p\ne2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Consider the elliptic curve in $F_p$ and let $n$ be the order of the group.

1. Suppose the curve is the same as bitcoin: $y^2 = x^3 + 7$, I have a point $P=(x,y)$，how to compute $\frac{1}{2}P$.
2. Suppose $P=aG$ for some base point $G$(we know the points $P,G$, but the coefficient $a$)，then is there efficient method to compute $\lfloor\frac{a}{2}\rfloor$G

Comment: Can you give the point doubling formula for this curve?

Comment: Anyway, the answer to the second question is surely negative. For otherwise the DLP would be trivial :-)

Comment: More seriously, if the order of $G$ is an odd number $\ell=2k-1$, then $\frac12aG$ exists for all $a$. This is because $\frac12 G=kG$. And if the order is even then $\frac12P$ either does not exist, or it has two possible answers. Again killing this line of attack to the DLP.

Comment: If $p \equiv 2\bmod 3$ then every element of $F_p$ has a unique 3rd root so $\# E(F_p)= p+1$, if the order of $P$ is odd then $\frac{p+1}{2^m} P=O$ where $2^m$ is the largest power of $2$ dividing $p+1$ so that $P=2 R$ where $R= \frac{p+1+2^m}{2^{m+1}} P$.

Comment: There are researches on this [Quartic equations and 2-division on elliptic
curves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.4379.pdf). Also, you can see this post [Point halving on elliptic curves of even order](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66106/18298) on Cryptography.SE

Comment: It should be noted that this question is not quite well definied. The map $[2] : E \to E$ has degree $4$, hence there can be up to $4$ "halves" of $P \in E$ (and there are precisely $4$ if $K$ is algebraically closed)

Comment: What @Mummytheturkey said is, of course, correct. But in the crypto side, in characteristic two, there is something called "halve-and-add" -algorithm (in addition/contrast to the more common "double-and-add"). I don't remember the details, but it offered some advantage in some situation. Anyway, on an abelian group of odd order halving is a well-defined process :-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to look for an informative link [within a search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22halve+and+add%22+elliptic&t=ffnt&ia=web).

Answer (score 0):

**Case $P = \lfloor \frac a 2 \rfloor G$;**

As said in the comments if possible this can help to break the DLog.

**Case $P = \frac a 2 G$;**

We may expect that it has two solutions $$P =\frac{x}{2} \cdot G =\frac{x + q}{2} \cdot G$$, however, the base point $G$ of the bitcoin curve has odd order. Therefore

```
int("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141", 16)
115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
```

Therefore if there exists half of a point then it is [unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1736008/338051).

1. The derivative of the equation $y^2 = x^3 + 7$

$\lambda = \dfrac{3x^{2}}   
    {2(x^{3}  + 7)^{1/2}} \tag{1} \label{1}$

2. Write down the equation for the tangent line to $E$ at G:

$$y-p_y = \lambda(x-p_1) => y = \lambda(x - p_x) + p_y \tag{2}$$

3. Write the equation for the intersection of the tangent line with E:

$$y^{2} = (\lambda(x - p_x) + p_y)^{2} = x^{3} + 7 \tag{3}\label{3}$$

4. Write down $\lambda$ in terms of $p_x$:

   If we extend the equation \ref{3} we will get a monic cubic polynomial, so the coefficient of $x^2$ will be the minus the sum of the roots. Therefore, $p_x$ will be double and $g_x$ will be a single root.  $$(\lambda (x - p_x) + p_y)^{2} = x^{3} + 7$$  $$\lambda^2 (x - p_x)^2 + 2 \lambda (x - p_x) p_y + p_y = x^{3} + 7$$ as we can see the term for $x^2$ is $\lambda$. Since the roots are the intersection point then $p_x$ will be a double point and $g_x$ will be a single point, so $2 p_x + q_x = \lambda^2$ $$\lambda^2 = 2 p_x + q_x  \label{4}\tag{4}$$
5. Form equation using equation \ref{4} and and replacing $x$ with $p_x$ in the equation \ref{1};

   $$\lambda^{2} = 2p_x + q_x  =  \dfrac{9p_x^{4}}{4(p_x^{3}  + 7)} \tag{5} \label{5}$$ Simplify this equation and move everything over to the left-hand side will yield  $$ (2p_x + q_x)(4(p_x^{\,3}  + 7))  =  9p_x^{\,4}\\ -p_x^4 + 4 p_x^3 q_x + 56 p_x + 28 q_x= 0$$  a quartic polynomial in $p_x$. The roots of this polynomial are the x-coordinates of the half points of $G$. We are in the odd case, the factors of the quartic polynomial will be a linear equation and an irreducible resolvent cubic.

Small, SageMath Validation;

```
#Secp256K1 prime
p = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f
#Secp256K1 order
q =  115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
#One of the roots
t = 82764486716702815285605477501188164702466527314352175978120539775788537185277
print("Expected root ", t)


#define ring of polynomials
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(p),'x')

# x-coordinate of Q where Q = [2]P
qx =  Integer(84538659774007663836420160802839342215744092791779235474817172502887599548487)


#From equation (5)
g = (2 *x + qx)*(4*(x^3+7)) - (3*x^2)^2

gRoots = g.roots()

print("The roots of quartic = ", gRoots)

gEvalAt_t = ((2 *t + qx)*(4*(t^3+7)) - (3*t^2)^2 ) % p

print( "gg(t) =", gEvalAt_t)
```

Outputs

```
Expected root  82764486716702815285605477501188164702466527314352175978120539775788537185277
The roots of quartic =  [(82764486716702815285605477501188164702466527314352175978120539775788537185277, 1)]
gg(t) = 0
```

---

Note: this result is similar to this article

- [Quartic equations and 2-division on elliptic
  curves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.4379.pdf),  George H. Hitching, 2018